# DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#variant_youth00[youth][front_image]_modal'

Tags: jquery

I am getting below error when I debug jquery on chrome.

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': DOMException:
>   Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#variant_youth00[youth][front_image]_modal' is not a valid selector.
>   at Function.ga [as find]   (/assets/js/jquery.min.js:2:7037)
>   at n.fn.init.find (/assets/js/jquery.min.js:2:23410)
>   at new n.fn.init (/assets/js/jquery.min.js:2:23954)
>   at n (/assets/js/jquery.min.js:2:405)
>   at HTMLButtonElement. (/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:19407)
>   at HTMLDocument.dispatch (/assets/js/jquery.min.js:3:6466)
>   at HTMLDocument.r.handle (/assets/js/jquery.min.js:3:3241)

`#variant_youth00[youth][front_image]_modal` this my bootstrap modal id and its not opening. Wired thing is it was working perfectly fine yesterday.

Comment: escaping `[]` might help, as in `\\[youth\\]`

Comment: Given that the `[]` characters need escaping I don't see how this was working yesterday. Try `document.querySelectorAll('#variant_youth00\\[youth\\]\\[front_image\\]_modal');`

Comment: Rory thanks for quick reply. I didnt get that can you please tell me where do I need to make this change.